# Apply Case to get all records from SQL

Tags: sql, case

I am applying one query where I need to either get results for single department or all department.

```
PersonID PersonName
1           'Abc'
2           'CDE'
3           'xyz'

DepartmentID   DepartmentName
1                   'Accounts'
2                   'Finance'

HirarchyID personID DepartmentID
1              1       1
2              1       1
3              2       1
```

Now I want that in my sql query I have a parameter which pass as `1 = 'Accounts', 2='Finance' and 0 = 'Both'`

How would I apply this @department parameter in my query ?

I tried applying with case but it will just allow me either accounts or finance.. but not both.

```
select * from persons p join
Hierarchy h on h.PersonID = p.PersonID JOIN
Department d on d.DepartmentID = h.DepartmentID
where case ???
```

My sample where clause in my query goes something like this :

```
WHERE        (sa.Area in (case when @myMode = 1 THEN 'abc Mode' 
                            when @myMode = 2 THEN 'XYZ Mode' 
                            ELSE
                            'abc Mode,xyz Mode'
                            END))
```

Comment: This is just an example of what I am trying to achieve.. My query is quite complex and there is one where clause where I need to apply such case

Answer (score 1):

Invert the condition by supplying the variable as the left hand side of an `in()`:

```
select * from mytable
where @department in (DepartmentID, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@DepartmentID is parameter that you are passing as "DepartmentID"

If(@DepartmentID=1)
begin
    --your code
    select * from Department  where DepartmentID  =1
end
else if(@DepartmentID=2)
begin

    --your code
    select * from Department  where DepartmentID  =2
end
else if(@DepartmentID=0)
begin

    select * from Department  where DepartmentID  in(1,2)

end
```

I hope this will help....

Comment: How would I satisfy 3 conditions ? 1,2 and 0(for all)

Comment: What if I am passing names and I dont have ID ?

Comment: I dont have ID, I just have to search by names. so how would in (accounts, finance) work ?

Comment: Can't paste code containing a bunch of `@` symbols, so I submitted my own answer to address your comment.

Comment: But you said that " I have a parameter which pass as 1 = 'Accounts', 2='Finance' and 0 = 'Both' " in question

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
-- populate a temp table for demo purposes only
select *
into #departments
from (
    select 1 as DepartmentId, 'Accounts' as DepartmentName
    union all
    select 2 as DepartmentId, 'Finance' as DepartmentName
) as q1

declare @deptName nvarchar(50) = 'Accounts';
declare @deptId int = coalesce((
    select DepartmentId
    from #departments
    where DepartmentName = @deptName
),0);

select *
from #departments -- or dbo.someOtherTable ... which would make more sense
where @deptId in(DepartmentId,0)
go
```

This will return records for `Accounts` department only.

Conversely, if you want all departments, change this line of code as follows:

```
declare @deptName nvarchar(50) = '';
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT  person_table.*
  FROM  person_table        ,
    department_table    ,
    heirarchy_table
 WHERE person_table.person_id       = heirarchy_table.person_id
   AND department_table.department_id   = heirarchy_table.department_id
   AND department_table.department_id = CASE WHEN (:PASSEDPARM = '0') THEN department_table.department_id
                                        ELSE :PASSEDPARM
                                        END;
```

db2 syntax used